# What is the best way to convert my input text to output in linux shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ksh

I am trying to format below text file in linux. could you pls suggest what is the best way to achieve my output.

Input text

```
Header| Header Identifier
[2017-02-03 14:23:44,066] - Message 1
[2017-02-03 14:23:45,066] - Message 1
[2017-02-03 14:23:46,066] - Message 1
[2017-02-03 14:23:47,066] - Message 1
Trailer | Trailer Identifer
Header| Header Identifier
[2017-02-03 14:23:44,066] - Message 2
[2017-02-03 14:23:45,066] - Message 2
[2017-02-03 14:23:46,066] - Message 2
[2017-02-03 14:23:47,066] - Message 2
Trailer | Trailer Identifer
```

Output I am trying to generate

```
Header| Header Identifier
[2017-02-03 14:23:44,066] - Message 1
Trailer | Trailer Identifer
Header| Header Identifier
[2017-02-03 14:23:44,066] - Message 2
Trailer | Trailer Identifer
```

Thanks in advance!

Update : I am not trying to remove duplicates here, I want to keep the record with lowest timestamp and remove others.

Comment: Something like `awk '!a[$0]++' file` should work (you'll have to play around with field separators). This question is pretty common for bash, but I can't find an exact duplicate

Comment: @Aserre: On a second look, this doesn't look like a duplicate of the one you posted. OP wants to re-order input file to output shown. I'm assuming, output will have reformatted multiple lines

Comment: @Inian Yeah, I didn't notice the timestamp were not exactly identical in OP's input. Also, if message 1 and message 2 are not unique, one would have to treat the log messages according to the `Header/Trailer` blocks.

Comment: @Abhishek Narayan: Is the input always in sorted order as in your input or it need not be?

Comment: @Inian Exactly, message lines are not duplicates, it has different timestamp.

Comment: @Inian yea, input will be in sorted order.

Comment: @AbhishekNarayan, are you trying to remove lines that are repeated, or do you want to get the header repeated with the messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bash command for that: `uniq`. Type that command:

```
uniq -f3 file
```

You are lucky the command still works with your use case, there is no need to program with awk. I quote some part of man page:

uniq filters  **adjacent**  matching lines from INPUT (or standard input), writing to OUTPUT (or standard output).

The option -f3 avoids comparing the first 3 fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! you saved my day. It works perfectly. Since i am new here I am not able to upvote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Abhishek Narayan: Try:

```
awk --re-interval '/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/ && !Q{print;Q=1;next} !/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/{Q="";print}'  Input_file
```

Considering that your Input_file has sorted order of dates. I am checking for regex for a date then checking if variable named Q's value is null, printing the line and setting the value of Q to 1. So when line is not matching with date pattern it  is setting value of variable Q to null and print the line.